# existence of open ball containing closed ball

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $\Omega$ is an open subset of Euclidien space $\mathbb{R}^{N}$, $r >0$ and $D = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^{N}\mid \| x\|\leq r\}\subseteq \Omega$. Then, is there $R>0$ such that 
$$
D\subseteq \{x\in\mathbb{R}^{N}\mid\|x\|<R\}\subseteq \Omega
$$
?

I have no idea...

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Maybe use compactness..

Comment: I have no idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, otherwise by considering $R = r + \frac 1 n$, we see that there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ of points in $\Omega^c$, the complement of $\Omega$, such that $\|x_n\| \leq r + 1$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|x_i\| = r$, which by compactness of $\Omega^c \cap \{x \in \mathbb R^N \mid \|x\| \leq r + 1\}$ must contain a subsequence that converges to a point $y$ in $\Omega^c$. This forces $y$ to have norm $r$ and hence a contradiction with the assumption $D \subseteq \Omega$.